# I changed my Hotmail password on the web site and I cannot login from my mobile clients

Tags: outlook.com, passwords, mobile

I changed my Hotmail password from the `hotmail.com` web site. I have a few mobile clients that use Exchange protocols to access Hotmail. When I updated my mobile clients to the new password, they could not log in and told me `invalid username password`. I retyped the password carefully multiple times. I tried the POP3 protocol instead of Exchange. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured this out, but I wanted to post this here so others can learn. I could not find a good FAQ or help page to explain this.

I changed my password using the Hotmail.com web site last night. For good security, I selected a long password of 19 characters. Logging in from the web worked fine, but when I tried to update my password on my mobile devices I got invalid password error. I tried Exchange protocols and Pop3 protocols and the Microsoft Android Hotmail application. None worked with the new password.

I found a few articles today that described similar problems. These included

- http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&p=9909971
- http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=38c1a2b978455098&hl=en

In these forums people mentioned that Pop3/Exchange access to Hotmail may require shorter passwords than web access. I changed my password to a 12 character string and then I was able to successfully log in from my mobile devices.

So, be careful of your password length on Hotmail if you use Pop3 or Exchange to access your email.

Comment: Nice catch.. :)